# Difference between 1st and 2nd version of "How to Design Programs" (HTDP)

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, htdp

i searched the internet for hours, but didn't find a satisfying answer to what's the difference between the first and second version of HTDP (How to design programs)?

Why should I start with the second version, instead of the first one?
As the second edition is not completed yet, I fear that I might get to the point where I have to switch back to the first edition.

The problem is:

1. To which part/chapter of the first edition?
2. Can I switch back and forth at all? Isn't the second edition totally different structured? Or are the individual chapters between those two version compatible?

I hope, someone can help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with the second edition. Unless you are an instructor, use the draft version not the stable one.

Switch to the first edition for Parts V and VI for now. I am developing replacements now but no promises.

Parts VII and VIII will not be replaced.

Comment: Who downvoted Matthias Felleisen's answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can go quite a long way with the second edition, probably far enough that switching back to the first edition won't matter that much, if you need to do it at all. Starting with the second edition will probably result in a smoother entry into Racket, it has been in continuous development since the 1st edition was "frozen".

On the [first page](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/index.html) of the second edition the main high-level differences are listed.

---

Edit: Answers to the follow-up questions

Do not wait for something to be declared "complete" in a moving field such as programming. Start working on the 2nd edition, draft version if you're not using it in a classroom setting. Once you're done, you can skim most of the 1st edition, or continue with another book.

Of course you will miss "some concepts", if you only read one book by one team of authors. A book geared towards functional programming will not show you the beauty and power of Smalltalk's live-objects-all-the-way-down approach to programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me ask three more things:

1. Chapters I-IV (of 2nd edition) seem to be finished completely (are they?). Thus in order to access the content of chapter V and VI, I should read the corresponding chapters of the first edition? Same with intermezzos?

2. Do I miss any concepts for learning how to program/design programs only using 2nd edition. It seems that not only the imperative part has be omitted, but also the last two chapters of the first edition.

3. `Your thoughts about the draft version? Is there a lot of changes made to already existing chapters, or can I use it?